# Eclipse Plugin - Text Editor - SingleLineRule

Tags: regex, eclipse-plugin, text-editor

I've been trying to develop my own text editor through a eclipse plugin.

I would like just highlight some words in a text editor.

I wrote the following lines:

```
IToken xmlComment = new Token(TEXT_START);
new SingleLineRule("@st","art", textStart);
```

with these lines I have managed to highlight the word **@start**. But if I write any upper case letter is not longer highlighted.

It's any way to create a SingleLineRule with a **regular expresion**???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also regex don't work with PatternRule. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question:

To create rules for "words" we can use the **org.eclipse.jface.text.rules.WordRule** Object, its constructor has as arguments the following objects:

**word detector** It's a implementation of IWordDetector

**defaultToken** The token itself

**ignoreCase** Of course a boolean value to ignore case.

Then to add the words just call the addWord method

**myWordRule.addWord(myWord, myToken);**